# Querying an array of GeoPoints using Parse

Tags: arrays, parse-platform, geolocation, geopoints

I have an item that has multiple locations.  I currently store an array of GeoPoints as a field on "item" to keep track of these locations.  I want to see if one of the geopoints in the array lies within x amount of miles from a location and I want to return that item, along with any other items that contain a point within x miles.

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"item"];
[query whereKey:@"locations" nearGeoPoint:pfPoint withinMiles:miles];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"returned");
}];
```

I get the error "error=$nearSphere: only works on gepoints fields", which makes sense.  The field must be of type GeoPoint.  Can I do this from the Parse iOS SDK?